# css :not(), selectors and selecting descendants

Tags: css

Let's say I have :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test for :not</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="a">
            <p class="para">This line should be green.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <p class="para">This line should also be green.</p>
            <div class="ds">
                <p class="para">This is another line that should be yellow</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to select all the elements with `class="para"` but exclude those that are descendants of those elements that have a `class="ds"`. I have this CSS:

```
.ds { color: grey; border-style:solid; border-width:5px;}
                
.para {color:yellow;}
                
.para:not(.ds .para) {color:green; border-style:solid; border-width:5px;} //not working
```

So I assume I can only have simple selectors as part of `:not(S)`, I can't have `:not (X Y)`. I am running in both Chrome (18.0.1025.162 m) and Firefox (10). Any ideas?

**Please note**: That the query is part of a bigger issue, I have some code (in gwt) that is selecting a list of elements (e.g. with `class="para"`) from the DOM. However, I have found a bug that requires the exclusion of elements that are descendants of a particular set of elements (e.g those with a `class="ds"`).

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean "no control over the code"? What *do* you have control over?

Comment: It means that i am using a 3rd party library using gwt, all i am looking for is a style that i can apply to this specific call.

Comment: Ummm... call? What call?

Comment: Its irrelevant at this point, i think my question is clear enough

Comment: I have added a new note to describe why i need to do this, even though i think it is irrelevant, it is a shame that i came here to ask help for an issue that i have but instead my question is marked down simply because it cannot be answered.

Comment: Your question was marked down (not by me) because frankly, it's been badly asked. IMHO part of the reason is that you have ran foul of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you are not responsive to dialogue (at least with me). Just my opinion, cheers.

Comment: How was it badly asked, i wish i was told rather than being marked down. And with all due respect i modified my question several times and also to explain why i was asking this question. I asked a question but was given with the typical why does it need to be done this way response. Believe me if i could i wouldn't do it this way but sometimes we have to and you should know this.

Answer (score 17):

The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) that you can have any *simple selector* inside `:not`, where

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

So yes, you can't have a descendant selector `:not(X Y)`. There is also the problem that when using the descendant selector you can only express positives ("when X's ancestors include a Y") and not negatives ("when X's ancestors do *not* include a Y");

The most practical solution would be to *reverse* the CSS logic so that the negative you want to express becomes a positive:

```
.ds .para { background:gold; }
.para { background: green }
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/EqYTv/)**.

Comment: Please see the note i added to the original question.

Comment: In CSS 4, the :not pseudo class now accepts complex selectors, and that part of the spec is broadly supported - https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anot() - so this answer is out of date as of 2023.

Answer (score 4):

*Elements with class "para" excluding those that are immediate children of elements with class "ds"* is:

```
*:not(.ds) > .para
```

Comment: Won't work as it stands. Any other element in its hierarchy will match it. It'd only work for `>`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan You are correct, will work only for the immediate children.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: I mean, it'd only work if you changed the general descendant selector to the direct descendant selector  (`>`). Otherwise e.g. `<html>` will match `*:not(.ds)` and then it'll select all `.para` descendants of it.

Comment: It only works for direct descendants which is not what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be approaching it in the wrong way. Normal `.para` matches are *green*, and ones in `.ds` are yellow. To be sure, with the way you have it you would then need to remove the border once more, but that's not a problem.

```
.ds { color: grey; border-style:solid; border-width:5px;}

.para {color:green; border-style:solid; border-width:5px;}

.ds .para {color:yellow; border-style: none; }
```

This fits with what I see as the natural way of interpreting the formatting.