# Select recursive :last-child. Possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS, is it possible to recursively select all :last-child from body?

Given this markup:

```
<body>
  <div id="_1">
    <div id="_2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="_3">
    <div id="_4">
      <div id="_5"></div>
      <div id="_6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am looking for div no. 3, 4 and 6

Another way to put it is this:

```
body > :last-child,
body > :last-child > :last-child,
body > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child,
body > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child > :last-child {
  /* My stuff here */
}
```

But obviously this is not a good approach.

Comment: If one of the following were solved, we would be able to solve this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227375/css-not-selectors-and-selecting-descendants | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector by checking that there is no non-last parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately that's just about the only way to do it without modifying the HTML.

There has been [at least one request](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Mar/0531.html) for recursive versions of the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes, but it doesn't seem to have gained much favor. Notice it suggests nesting and repeating the pseudo-classes in the same way as in your question:

> Currently, AFAIK, we can only match children up to some *exact* nesting level known in advance (3 in the example below):
>
> ```
> .container > :first-child,
> .container > :first-child > :first-child,
> .container > :first-child > :first-child > :first-child {}
> ```
>
> We cannot use just :first-child context selector since it would also select first children of blocks that are not first children themselves.
>
> So we need a sort of *recursive* selector that matches not just first of last child, but recursively matches all first-most and last-most elements regardless of their nesting level.

Comment: Ok, I was affraid of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
body :last-child {
    color:red;
}
body :not(:last-child) :last-child {
    color:initial;
}
```

Any last-child element that's a descendant of one that's not a last-child will have the change reversed.

Comment: Any last-child element that's a descendant of one that's not a last-child will have the change reversed.

Comment: add this into the answer

Comment: This is tempting. But you have to be fine with having `color:initial;` on the non selected elements, or you have to fight it off with more specific selectors.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to chain all the way.** It would be simply like this

```
div:last-child {
   /* Your GREAT css */
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EyCq/)

**Update:** On that case, give the `div2` a typical class and use `:not()` to push out of the selection

```
div:last-child:not(.nolist) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HHKc7/1/)

Comment: That would also select div no. 2.

Comment: @LasseDahlEbert, Misunderstood the question. Its actually very simple. See the update and the demo :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not what I'm looking for. See this forked demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HHKc7/ - I don't want div 2

Comment: Hi Starx - thank for your effort, but I'm looking for a very general way of selecting 'the path of :last-child'. If I had a specific case, I would propably class my way out of trouble as you suggest.