# Best usage of CSS :last-child selector in nested elements

Tags: html, css

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3fnhmtz/3/

It's quite common to have `margin-bottom: 20px` on elements like `<p>` or `.button` as we tend to use these in page flow and these need breathing room.

But something i get stuck on quite often is removing this margin if it is the last element inside something like a `<div class="panel"></div>` that has some padding to it we get `20px + margin` at the bottom so we end up with a bigger space at the bottom than the top.

1 fix i normally use is: `.panel *:last-child *:last-child {` as bad as this is it works for the most part. But in the Fiddle you can see if you was using something like a `<dt>` it falls apart a bit.

I can't realistically go through and list every element that could possible be last so is there a better foolproof way to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not `margin-top: 20px;` and `.panel p:first-child{ margin-top: 0; }`?

Comment: It's still the same principle just reversed. That means i'd have to change all my `margin-bottoms` to `margin-top` and then just try and find a way to reset the top on all elements that could come first

Comment: I posted a bogus answer ... hadn’t read your question through ... sorry :)
Anyway, you could perhaps turn the problem on it’s head, and remove the bottom-padding in the parent?
... or look into forcing box-model-rendering, which I use all the time, with reliable results (not sure if that fixes your problem, but it might be worth some research).

Comment: I could remove the bottom padding but then sometimes elements have no `margin-bottom` so they would sit flush with the bottom. You could say i could add margin-bottom to the last item in the panel but i'm a bit back to square one with a struggle on how to target the last items i need

Comment: Find a nice reset.css (or take the trouble, and make your own)
+ force box-model-rendering.
(-moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;)

Comment: A reset.css wouldn't take away `margin` i've added myself to `<p>` tags or `<button>` as these need it to keep with the page flow in articles for example.

Comment: No, but a good reset will normalise all elements margin ... removing your odd-out problem with <dt> for instance. PS: <dt> looks fine here, on Mac/Safari ... that is what a reset.css is used for ... consistency.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a new JSFiddle showing the problem when using 3 floated buttons as well as it's not a `<dl>` specific problem

Answer (score 4):

While still valid, a lot of the answers are missing the point of your question, which is a more concise method to recursively drill down through the last children.

See this answer here: [Select recursive :last-child. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477272/select-recursive-last-child-possible)

So your only recourse may be to drill down with the wildcard selector.

```
.panel.two > *:last-child,
.panel.two > *:last-child > *:last-child,
.panel.two > *:last-child > *:last-child > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You may be able to create a recursive-check mixin using SASS, but I don't believe the elegant single attribute recursive application exists. :(

Comment: Yea this is another option i've explored which is soo dirty but the only thing i can think of tbh. If nothing else pops up then i'll just mark this as the answer as it's the only thing i can think of that works. Although i still do have the problem where it would target the last button. I almost need a `:last-of-type` somewhere but that would just cause more breakage than fixage

Comment: Keep hunting.  I'll be grateful to see if someone come up with something better. :)